# Not able to read date field in Pig using load and dump commands

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have some sample data of this type which I am trying to read and display on the console using LOAD and DUMP commands. I have created this CSV file in Ubuntu manually. As you can see at the bottom the dump command is displaying just a comma instead of the 'dob' field.

## emps.csv

```
1,John,35,M,101,50000.00,03/03/79
2,Jack,30,F,201,3540000.00,09/10/84
```

## Commands for loading data

```
empdata = load 'emps.csv'  using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,name:chararray,age:int,gender:chararray,deptId:int,sal:double,dob:datetime);
dump empdata;
```

## Command for displaying data

```
dump empdata;
```

## Output

```
(1,John,35,M,101,50000.0,)
(2,Jack,30,F,102,60000.0,)
```

As shown in the above output the 'dob' field value is missing and just displays comma. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

date time function is available with 0.11

look at the version you are using

```
empdata = load 'emps.csv'  using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,name:chararray,age:int,gender:chararray,deptId:int,sal:double,dob:chararray);
```

try using dob as chararray and do following steps

```
B = foreach empdata generate ToDate(dob,'string format'),$0,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5;

dump B;
```

Comment: I am using version 0.12